# Firebase Hosted JS Game Skipping Lines of Code

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I made a little game with HTML/JS/CSS to learn more javascript that I have hosted as a firebase web app right now. I was playing it after deploying and watching the console in Google chrome and realized that my game is passing over big important sections of code. I can link to the game if anyone wants to see these "skips" in action. My two big problems are that the tile sometimes returns true for an enemy but does not trigger a fight and sometimes the game does not check if the player should be alive. This doesn't happen every time, just some of the time. I can also share anything else from the project that would be helpful. This is really the first time I've used JS outside of simple  tags for a webpage so try not to judge it too harshly. Thanks in advance!

The pieces in question that are being skipped are:

```js
//decide if a tile has an enemy
function hasEnemy(){
    let roll = Math.random();
    console.log(roll);
    if(roll > .6666){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
//there is one gameView.onXClick for each cardinal direction.
//button functions
gameView.onNorthClick = function(){
    console.log("north");
    oPos = thePlayer.pos;
    if ((thePlayer.pos - 5) < 0){
        null;
    }else{
        thePlayer.pos -= 5;
        gameView.updateLoc(oPos, thePlayer.pos);
        if(thePlayer.pos == 12){
            gameView.updateNar("You are home");
            gameView.homeMenu();
        }else{
            gameView.updateNar("You travel North");
            console.log(hasEnemy());
            if(hasEnemy()){
                fightEnemy();
            }else{
                this.updateNar("Nothing around...");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and a very important piece of the game:

```js
//player hits
gameView.onHitClick = function(){
    console.log("You Hit");
    thePlayer.hp = thePlayer.hp - curEnemy.atk;
    curEnemy.hp = curEnemy.hp - thePlayer.atk;
    gameView.updateFight(thePlayer.hp, thePlayer.atk, thePlayer.def, curEnemy.hp, curEnemy.atk, curEnemy.def);
    this.updateNar("You hit for " + thePlayer.atk);
    if(enemyLive(curEnemy.hp) == false){
        this.updateNar("You beat the enemy");
        thePlayer.kc += 1;
        thePlayer.exp += curEnemy.expw;
        thePlayer.gold += curEnemy.gold;
        gameView.mapScene();
        gameView.moveMenu();
        gameView.updateLoc(oPos, thePlayer.pos);
    }else if(playerLive(thePlayer.hp) == false) {
        gameView.loseScene(thePlayer.kc, thePlayer.gold);
        gameView.loseMenu();
    }
}
//check if the player is alive
function playerLive(php){
    if(php <= 0){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add snippets relevant to your problem, you say `hasEnemy` returns true but does not trigger, but we never see where `hasEnemey` is called, try to isolate the problem as much as possible.

Comment: Agreed with @S.Visser here: there's simply not enough information here. In order to help, we'll need to see the [minimal, complete/standalone code that we can all use to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This typically works best if you start reproducing the problem from scratch, rather than trying to extract it from your complete game.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry, I added where hasEnemy gets called to the original post, if this isn't enough information, I will try to minimize it as such. I believe my problem is having too many if statements nested and the browser is not waiting enough time for the code to decide what should happen next but I'm really not sure.